# socket.io cors error . i try to connect socket.io in laravel vuejs but cors error getting

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, socket.io

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://dolphin.test:3001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Ni7Nzha' from origin 'http://dolphin.test' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

i try to connect socket.io in vuejs but code give me cors error

Server side code :->

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
const axios = require('axios'); 
const fs = require('fs');
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

const options = {};
const server = http.Server(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(3001,function(){
    console.log('server running on port 3001');
});

var clients = {};
var connected_users = [];


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
 console.log("connection establish");
  socket.send('Hello!');
  socket.on('add-user', function(data) {
    clients[data.userId] = {
     "socket": socket.id,
   };
  connected_users.push(data.userId);
  io.sockets.emit('connected-users', { users_connected: connected_users });
});

socket.on('chat-message', function(data){
  if (clients[data.user_id]) {
    io.sockets.connected[clients[data.user_id].socket].emit("chat-message", data);
    // console.log(data);
  } else {
    console.log("User does not exist: ");         
  }
});

//Removing the socket on disconnect
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
 for(var name in clients) {
  if(clients[name].socket === socket.id) {
    delete clients[name];
    break;
  }
 }  
})
});
```

Client side code :->

```
import io  from 'socket.io-client';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isActive : '',
            activeId : '' ,
            isImageLoaded : false,
            user : {},
            src : '',
            siteSettings : {},
            form: new Form(),
            socket : io("http://dolphin.test:3001"),  
        }
    },
    async created() {
        this.showData();
        
        this.socket.on('connection', (socket) => {
            console.log('Admin user connected');
            // socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            //     console.log('user disconnected');
            // });
        });
         this.socket.on('add-user', function (data) {
             console.log(data);
        });
    },
```

i was added middleware in laravel but same error

```
 return $next($request)
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, 
 OPTIONS');
```

and also  i am doing this on local server not on live server and i make virtual host on system and try to work on dolphine.test is local server

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Add a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your backend on the client response: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin Why use the `cors` module in the first place when you dont configure it properly/or need it?

Comment: i am using only for cors . i configure it but it give me same error so i remove it and i also try to pass header in laravel middelware but not working

Comment: Laraval is not your server behind `http://dolphin.test:3001`. I suggest you to read the MDN article to full understand what CORS is and how it works. You have to configure `http://dolphin.test:3001`  & `http://dolphin.test` properly to work with cors.

Comment: okay i will check

Answer (score 0):

**This is my working example socket with SSL (Vue/Laravel - Node js)**

> If you wanna use https with Socket you must generate self signed certificate here is link:
> [How To Create a Self-Signed SSL Certificate](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04)

**Backend Nodejs**

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");
const cors = require("cors");
const pino = require("pino");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const socketIO = require("socket.io");
const logger = pino({
  prettyPrint: {
   ignore: "pid, hostname",
  },
});


const app = express();
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());

//In this case my ssl keys located outside root folder so the path is ../myssl.key
const server = https.createServer(
  {
    key: fs.readFileSync("../ssl.key"),
    ca: fs.readFileSync("../ssl.ca"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("../ssl.cert"),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    secure: true,
  },
  app
);

server.listen(5000, () => {
  logger.info(`[server]: Started on port 5000`);
});


//Here you slove  Cors problem!
const io = socketIO(server, {
  cors: {
    origins: "*:*",
    method: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH"],
  },
  transports: ["websocket", "polling", "flashsocket"],
  reconnection: false,
  handlePreflightRequest: (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "my-custom-header",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
    });
    res.end();
  },
});

io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
  logger.info("[socket]: New connection...");
  socket.emit("userConnected");
  socket.on("disconnect", async () => {
    console.log("Session closed..");
  });
});
```

**Frontend Vue/Laravel**

> resources/js/plugins/socket.io

```
import Vue from "vue"
import VueSocketIO from "vue-socket.io"
import SocketIO from "socket.io-client"

Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
   debug: false,
   connection: SocketIO("https://yourewebsite.com:5000", {
   autoConnect:false
},
  secure:true 

});
```

**Hope this was useful for you**

Comment: okay . Thank you this code also useful for me

Comment: @PawanManka very glad to help you )